# Python extract zip file avoiding junk paths

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, unzip

In ubuntu, when extracting a zip file, there is an option `-j` that:

```
junk paths.  The archive's directory structure is  not  recreated;  all  files  are
              deposited in the extraction directory (by default, the current one).
```

I am searching this kind of option in python but did not find anything succesful for my code:

```
 with zipfile.ZipFile(my_file) as zip_ref:
     zip_ref.extractall(my_path)
```

How can I handle this situation?

Thank you very much for your information!